# Populate formulas upon submission of a form

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I need some help to automate a sheet that receives data from g-forms.  I am trying to use the index-match function but learned that it does not work well with array-formula.

Basically what I want to do is to look up the data related to the "SF NAme" inputted to the form and append to the sheet where the responses are inputted.

Here is the sheet I am trying to work with.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MDKJqaK20zl2xRR0_yBk8TTkKrCgEyQzz2myGwuK634/edit?usp=sharing

or would it be better to use scripts... though I am not that familiar with the google appscripts.

Comment: Hi, Your spreadsheet is not accessible. Can you fix permissions?

Comment: Sorry for that.  I have changed the settings now

Comment: Is this a result you want in column AJ of Form Responses 1?  If so, what is the issue with your current formula in AJ2.  Can you explain, or show, what exact result you are expecting, and in which cells, given your current data?  Maybe adding a few more lines of data will also help make this clearer.

Comment: Also, when collecting form responses, it is sometimes quite useful to move any arrayformulas up into the first/header row, but including the column header text in the arrayformula.  Something like the following, put in AJ1:                                                                                  ={"Agent's First Name";ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank($E$2:$E),"",index('Lookup Data'!$A:$E,match(E2:E,'Lookup Data'!$A:$A,0),2)))}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the range AG2:AJ and enter in AG2

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(E2:E), vlookup(E2:E, 'Lookup Data'!A2:F, {6, 5, 4, 2}, 0),))
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion regarding the header rows.... Though I still could not get the results I want for AG to AI... I need them to get the values found on Form Details based on the value under the column Agent's SF name in the "Audit Dump".  The formula above returns an error when I put it on AG2